# How to allow the user to upload new music to an audio source which is tied to a button?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, filesystems, audio-source

I'm trying to build an app where a user can play music and mix multiple audio. I not getting an idea on how to allow the user to upload his/her own music file to the audio source which is tied to a toggle button. How i have planned to make this work is: There is a grid of toggle buttons on the screen. An edit button at the bottom. when i click on edit button the camera switches to another with a replica of this current canvas, where when u click on the buttons you should be able to upload audio files from local storage on the phone.

Please guide me as to how i have to go about this.

Comment: You haven't shown any effort. This website does not provide code. Post the relevant code and if there are any issues or errors, somebody will help you.

Comment: I'm not looking for the actual code so i can copy paste it. I was trying to see if some one had done something similar to this. I was actually finishing up another part of the same app.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting an file from the filesytem can be a bit tricky within Unity, I would use a library from the asset store for that

This one is free and should work on android.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/simple-file-browser-98451

To load the selected Audio file as an AudioClip you can use the `WWW` class like this:

```
public void StartLoadingAudio(string path) {
    StartCoroutine(LoadAudio(path));
}

IEnumerator LoadAudio(string path)
{
    WWW www = new WWW("file://" + path);
    yield return www;
    AudioClip clip = www.GetAudioClip();
    //Do something with the AudioClip
}
```

Call the StartLoadingAudio function with the path you got from the File Browser

Comment: Steffan you saved my day again man, this was getting on my nerves, Thank you a lot!!